# Using Node.js to add Object in a MongoDB Array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a great problem with a school project:

I created a site that uses MongoDB as DataBase and Node.js as Server, in the server I have a method to add products to a cart, the object that i'm trying to add to the cart array is this:

```
{"cart" : {"idproduct" : idproduct, "collectionproduct" : 'comicbooks'}}
```

And the code I'm using to add the object to the array is this:

```
db.collection("users").update({"_id": new ObjectId(userid)}, {$push: {"cart" : {"idproduct" : new ObjectId(idproduct), "collectionproduct" : 'comicbooks'}}}, { "$upsert": true });
```

The real strange thing is that I've tried it on mongo itself, and it worked, but when I try to run the node code then it doesn't, but it doesn't even give me an error.

I even tried the same thing with `$addToSet` and again, with node doesn't work but it doesn't give me any error, but in mongo it works.

If anyone knows what is the problem then please, please help me, as quick as you can.

Comment: are you like using mongoose to connect to mongoDB or just the mongoDriver?

Comment: Just mongoDriver I guess

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native), then try this

```
var insertDocuments = function(db, callback) {
  var collection = db.collection('users');
  collection.insert([
    "cart" : {"idproduct" : idproduct, "collectionproduct" : 'comicbooks'}}
  ], function(err, result) {
    callback(result);
  });
}
```

and call the function using

```
insertDocuments(db, function() {
  db.close();
});
```

Is this answer your question?

Comment: What is the problem?, maybe give me more code on how you connect to your mongo server

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't give any error, but it doesn't execute the operation, if I do a db.users.find().pretty() on mongo after I launched the function I expect to see in the user that clicked the button cart array the object I'm trying to insert. I don't exactly know where is the problem actually, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I tryed your code again with a console.log("we are here"); and I noticed something strange: the log didn't appeared, so there's something that doesn't allow the function to work, anyway it still doesn't give me any error and still does not add the object to any user, but this is a good point to start with, I'll try to figure out what isn't working and than tell you.